# Get JSON API Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, json, api, phonegap

```
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://navkolosvity.com.ua/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
ourRequest.onload = function(){
    if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest < 400) {
        var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
        console.log(data);
    }else{
        console.log("We conect to the server, but it returent an error.");
    }
};

ourRequest.onerror = function(){
    console.log("Conection error!");
}

ourRequest.send();
```

и тут у меня Error

```
 Refused to connect to 'https://navkolosvity.com.ua/wp-json/wp/v2/posts' 
 because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
 "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note 
that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы используете [Content Security Plugin](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-content-security-policy/) со стандартными настройками, вам нужно разрешить брать данные из источника https://navkolosvity.com.ua по настройке плагина смотрите в документацию на плагин